# Using Java Runtime and Process classes to execute C code vs using native interface

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I’m considering using C to do some of the backend processing for my application, at least for a learning experience if nothing else.

Normally what I’d do is write a C program as a stand-alone shell command, and use `Process.exec` to run it and get results back.

But the thought of overhead came to mind. How much overhead would it create to invoke a shell process every single time one of these C programs needs to be called? Is it better to use the JNI for performance improvements?

The application would be hosted on a server and would have to deal with numerous simultaneous requests, so my gut feeling is that JNI is the more efficient way. But I don’t know enough about this area yet, so some guidance on how it would impact performance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to start here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

You will get the feeling of how to deal with JNI. I start with simple things and then, I move towards more complex topics - you will probably face most of them while dealing with JNI.

I suggest to start with simple Hello World - just to make sure, you have working env.

And, when it comes to performance. I would suggest following test. Try to run "Hello world" as standalone process and then, via JNI and compare results :)

Most preferably, run it for a longer time ;)

Just to give you dirty, ugly, bold, estimate. Lets say you want to print "Hello world!" using JNI vs. Process builder - 1000 times.

```
JNI: 4ms
Process: 3275ms
```

**Update**

If you want to make some tests just do following

```
git clone https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook.git
cd jnicookbook/recipes/recipeNo033
make
make test
```

Have fun with JNI!

Comment: Wow, that’s a huge time difference! Thanks for the info, I’ll be sure to check it out.